# Nested Switch (troubles with input)

Tags: c#, algorithm, switch-statement

I am new at programming and I was trying do create an algorithm that allows to decide either I want something written in Portuguese either I want something written in English. I get the structure of a nested switch however I don't have how can I make the input to decide what switch will be executed. Sorry if it's a silly question but I am new at programming.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int number, pt=0, en=0, language;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Insert a number from 1 to 5:");
            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) || number < 1 || number > 5);

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to see the number written in English or Portuguese/ (1  or 2)?");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out language);

            switch (pt)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("um");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("dois");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("três");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("quatro");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("cinco");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Insira um número de 1 a 5.");

                    switch (en)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("one");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("two");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("three");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Console.WriteLine("four");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Console.WriteLine("five");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Insert a number from 1 to 5.");
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why all these combersome `switch`es? Put *dictionary*:

```
   private static Dictionary<int, string> s_Digits_Pt = new Dictionary<int, string>
     {1, "um"},
     {2, "dois"},
     {3, "três"},
     {4, "quatro"},
     {5, "cinco"},
   };

   private static Dictionary<int, string> s_Digits_En = new Dictionary<int, string>
     {1, "one"},
     {2, "two"},
     {3, "three"},
     {4, "four"},
     {5, "five"},
   };
```

Having this collections you can put the logic as

```
   ...

   // Depending on the language required (Portuguese / English)
   // choose the right dictionary 
   Dictionary<int, string> dict = language == 1 
     ? s_Digits_Pt
     : s_Digits_En;

   if (dict.TryGetValue(number, out var result) // do we have a key (translation)? 
     Console.WriteLine(result);                 // yes - put the translation 
   else   
     Console.WriteLine(language == 1            // no - complain using the right language
        ? "Insira um número de 1 a 5." 
        : "Insert a number from 1 to 5.");
```

Answer (score 0):

`switch` isn't scalable solution

try use `Dictionary` (very fitting for translation)

```
Dictionary<string, string> enVocabulary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {"1", "one"},
  {"2", "two"},
  {"3", "three"},
  {"4", "four"},
  {"5", "five"},
};

Dictionary<string, string> ptVocabulary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {"1", "um"},
  {"2", "dois"},
  {"3", "três"},
  {"4", "quatro"},
  {"5", "cinco"},
};

Console.WriteLine("Do you want to see the number written in English or Portuguese/ (1  or 2)?");
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out language);

Dictionary<string, string> vocabulary;
if (language == 1) 
   vocabulary = enVocabulary;
else if (language == 2) 
   vocabulary = ptVocabulary;
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unknown language");
    return;
}

do
{
    Console.Write("Type something: ");
    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    if (text == "quit") break;
    string translation;
    if (vocabulary.TryGetValue(text, out translation))
       Console.WriteLine(translation);
    else
       Console.WriteLine("Cannot translate");
} 
while (true);
```